# Authorise with Basic Auth every request Spring Boot

Tags: spring, basic-authentication

I am building a REST api with different paths that control the data input from a mobile application (which u guessed it, it plays the role of the frontend). I am still in the very first stage of the app development and now I am testing my authorisation session. I have chosen basic auth (httpBasic() - as the method is named) and I want that every request that the mobile app does to the server, I want that to be authenticated. Because, at the moment, if I authenticate once, next time, it does not require to sent the authentication data. Is this possible? This is the function for the authorisation:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and().logout()
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your custom `Success Handler` to handle it.

Like :

```
.logout()
    .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            CustomerUserDetails userDetails = (CustomerUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            String username = userDetails.getUsername();

            System.out.println("The user " + username + " has logged out.");

            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
        }
    })
    .permitAll();
```

Check it - [Here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-security-logout-success-handler-example)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, If I will ask for an authentication will I overload the system more? Or will I increase the overall running time of the algorithm? Is it fine if I do so?

Comment: It completely depends on how you want to implement you system.  And , it would be an overhead . Handlers works as hooks where you can get extra work done to make system more flexible. So, it upto your system design.

Comment: @TasteMyBomb  : hope this answers your question .